# How to secure subdomain on godaddy when its pointing to AWS EC2 tomcat?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, godaddy

My domain and subdomain are currently setup on GoDaddy and I have a web portal running on tomcat on an AWS EC2 Windows instance. I have configured tomcat to run on HTTPS port 443. I set the forwarding rules with masking to point my subdomain to my EC2 instance -

- domain - www.example.co.uk
- subdomain - portal.example.co.uk forwards to `https://some ip:443`

I created a keystore and CSR for my tomcat installation and bought a basic SSL Certificate for portal.example.co.uk and imported it into my tomcat keystore.

When I go to portal.example.co.uk it appears to be http as opposed to https.

I guess this is a 2 fold question...

If a subdomain forwards to an HTTPS address, should that request then show as HTTPS?

When trying to secure a subdomain, can you do this by installing a certificate on the EC2 instance or do I need to do it from GoDaddy?

When I spoke to GoDaddy about it, they said in order to do what im trying to achieve, I would need to pay £200+ for a wildcard certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Just pointing the subdomain to an HTTPS address doesn't make the site run on HTTPS.

Instead you need to do the following

1. Generate a CSR (Certificate Signing Request) from TomCat
2. Purchase a WildCard Certificate (to cover the domain and subdomains) from GoDaddy or anyone else or generate your own using OpenSSL (there might be a problem with some browsers not recognising the root certificate)
3. Generate a Certficate using the CSR
4. Upload the Certificate to Tomcat
5. Change the Site configuration in tomcat to load this certficate and switch when a request for HTTPS ismade from a browser
6. Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS requests in your site configuration

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I am only interested in securing my subdomain, do I still need a wildcard certificate? I have a certificate on tomcat at the moment with the domain set to e.g. portal.example.co.uk

Comment: No, you don't need a wildcard... but you have to get rid of the "forwarding and masking" nonsense and create a standard DNS record.

Comment: Great thanks I have deleted the forward and created an new 'A' record. Guessing I'll need to wait a bit for the change to propagate.

Comment: It doesnt appear to be possible with GoDaddy. It only lets you specify an ip address and doesnt allow for port. I am currently getting a timeout why i access e.g. portal.example.co.uk, however if I access portal.example.co.uk:8443 then it works and shows as Secure  -https://uk.godaddy.com/community/Managing-Domains/Domain-to-IP-at-Specific-Port/td-p/52018

Comment: I'll try and add a redirect on tomcat

Comment: Thats it working!! Thanks very much for your help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can [migrate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/MigratingDNS.html) your Domain to Route 53 (this is optional)

Using [AWS Certificate manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-request.html), which is free, request a certificate for portal.example.co.uk and [place it on an Elastic Load Balancer (ELB).](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/ssl-server-cert.html)

Point portal.example.co.uk to the ELB (using a CNAME if using Godaddy or an alias in route 53) and Setup Tomcat to redirect the site to https.

Between the client and ELB will be encrypted but between the ELB and tomcat server will http, which can be locked via security groups so only the ELB can access the tomcat servers.